# What exactly is the def tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The [def](/questions/tagged/def) tag has no tag wiki, and at to me, at a glance, does not seem to be one tag, but rather a collection of questions which mention [def](/questions/tagged/def) at some point.

What is the proper usage of the [def](/questions/tagged/def) tag?  What does [def](/questions/tagged/def) mean?

Examples:

- [.def files C/C++ DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366228/def-files-c-c-dlls)
- [Nine ways to define a method in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303817/scala-9-ways-to-define-a-method)
- [python positional args and keyword args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486067/python-positional-args-and-keyword-args)
- [Alternative to #define for flexibility in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100963/alternative-to-define-for-flexibility-in-c)

Comment: A quick glance at the 86 questions leads to the conclusion that this def has too many definitions.

Comment: Well, def in Python defines a method... it seems kinda pointless for Python questions.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards It'd be like having a method tag when talking about other OOP oriented questions... oh wait! ;) (but yes, I agree, it seems pointless)